# Mailchimp api to subscribe using java script request issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying below javascript code to subscribe on mailchimp. flow wise working good but i am getting error like not authorize because may be i am not passing api key correctly. please help to solve my issue

```
var request = new Request('https://<dc>.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/[listid]/members', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    mode: 'no-cors',
                    json: {
                        "email_address": "am_it@live.com",
                        "status": "subscribed",
                    },
                    redirect: 'follow',
                    headers: new Headers({
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': 'Basic apikey'
                    })
                });

// Now use it!
                fetch(request).then(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your authentification details with your username and api key. You can do it with the `auth` parameter:

```
auth: {
    'user': 'yourUserName',
    'pass': 'yourApiKey'
}
```

Just add that to your request object:

```
Request('https://<dc>.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/[listid]/members', {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'no-cors',
                json: {
                    "email_address": "am_it@live.com",
                    "status": "subscribed",
                },
                redirect: 'follow',
                headers: new Headers({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Basic apikey'
                }),
                auth: {
                    'user': 'yourUserName',
                    'pass': 'yourApiKey'
                }
            });
```

I looked at the documentation in the getting started section of the developer mailchimp api: [here](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/) and I converted the `curl` examples to javascript code using [this page](https://curl.trillworks.com/#node). Let me know if it worked.

Comment: i tried that i am getting this errors : OPTIONS https://<dc>.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/listid/members 401(Unauthorized)

(index):1 Fetch API cannot load https://<dc>.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/listid/members. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
Failed to fetch

Comment: Change your request url because `https://<dc>` <- is not a valid url. From the mailchimp api: 

`The <dc> part of the URL corresponds to the data center for your account. For example, if the last part of your MailChimp API key is us6, all API endpoints for your account are available at https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/.`

Then you must allow cross origin request. Change your: `mode: 'no-cors'` to `mode: 'cors'`. 

Also you have to change the `[listid]` parameter of the url to a list url of your account. You can see the list id in your dashboard inside mailchimp I believe.

Comment: yes that is i am already doing. i just put <dc> when i post on stackoverflow. i am though getting errors

Comment: Make sure that your request `mode` is set to `mode: 'cors'`.

Comment: That error you get is saying that the mailchimp's server are not allowing request from `localhost` so you should make this request from a public IP.

Comment: are you sure that we use live server it will solve that unauthorized and cross origin erros ?

Comment: I recommend you to read this article https://jvaneyck.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/cross-domain-requests-in-javascript/ it will explain all you need to do this. If I understood correctly what you have to do is create a proxy server. Unfortunately I cannot help you do it because I don't know how and don't have the time right now.